# rosdep atp-get install dependency

Tags: ros, rosdep, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all,

I have created a catkin package and it has an external dependence to work properly. The dependence is "libmodbus-dev", which can be installed by "apt-get install libmodbus-dev" command.
I would like to install it automatically by rosdep. In other words,  when somebody compile the package with catkin make / catkin make install, the external dependence "libmodbus-dev" will be installed automatically, and for each compilation it will check whether the dependence is installed or not.

Is possible something like this?   What have i to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173238/rosdep-atp-get-install-dependency/) by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 375 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to install it automatically by rosdep. [..] Is possible something like this? What have i to do?

That is certainly possible. `libmodbus-dev` would become a system dependency of your package, and if there are no existing rules for it, you would have to contribute them. The rosdep documentation should clarify things for you. See the [Contributing rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) section of the [rosdep](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-10**:
Note that rosdep will not be invoked automatically when compiling, but has to be called manually by the user from the command line (which is part of the default procedure for downloading and compiling new ros packages).